# delete /folder in url path with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made a website with all my pages except the index inside a "pages" folder 
and i want to make a rewriteRule that change :

www.mydomainname.com/pages/about.php

to

www.mydomainename.com/about.php

there is my actual .htacces that delete the .php of my pages but i can't find solution to delete the "pages" folder in my url path :

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below rule should work, but you have to make sure it is not conflicting with your other rules,

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

Comment: so actually i need to make a new RewriteCond ?

Comment: Use this rule into your root .htaccess or above all your rules without condition.